# Нужно изменить div при radio:checked

Tags: css, input, css-selectors, radio

```
<div id = "a" style = "w:100px; h:100px; bg-color:black"></div>
<input type = "radio" id = "b" name = "c"/>
```

Нужно чтобы при действии radio:checked менялся цвет блока #a.

Comment: Так можно сделать, только если `input` стоит до `div`

Comment: А javascript нельзя юзать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое можно сделать, только если `input` стоит перед `div`. Но если вам нужно именно такое положение, то можно использовать *flexbox* и заменить видимое расположение:

```css
.block {display:flex;}

.block input {order: 2;}
.block div {order: 1;}

input:checked + div {color: red}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="radio" name="c">
  <div>Text 1</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input type="radio" name="c">
  <div>Text 2</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <input type="radio" name="c">
  <div>Text 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Поиграйте со стилями, добавьте классы или id и отслеживайте с помощью css

```css
select {
  display: none;
}

input#radio_1:checked ~ #select_1{
  display: block;
}
input#radio_2:checked ~ #select_2{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_2">
    
    <select name="select_1" id="select_1">
        <option value="optin_1">option_1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select_1" id="select_2">
        <option value="optin_2">option_2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#b:checked ~ #a {
background-color:gray !important;
}
```

```html
<input type = "radio" id = "b" name = "c"/>
<input type = "radio" id = "c" name = "c"/>

<div id = "a" style = "width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
```